# how to display code editor html in output with "section" page scroll from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here my code editor html is

```
<div class="codecontainer" id="htmlContainer" style="max-width:30%;">
     <span class="containerTitle">HTML</span>
     <textarea class="code" id="html">

     </textarea>
</div>
```

And function call in run button click is

```
$("#run").click(function() {
    $('#resultFrame').contents().find('html').html("<style>" + $('#css').val() + "</style>" + $("#html").val());
    document.getElementById('resultFrame').contentWindow.eval($('#js').val());
});
```

how to use?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not explanatory , on some assumption for problem i have created a solution for you ..

So the following codes will run HTML input from text area and output in iframe ..

**HTML**

```
<div class="codecontainer" id="htmlContainer" style="max-width:30%;">
     <span class="containerTitle">HTML</span>
     <textarea class="code" id="html"></textarea>
    <button type="button" id="run">Run</button>
</div>
<iframe id='resultFrame'></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
$("#run").click(function() 
{
$('#resultFrame').contents().find('body')
.html("<style>" + $('#css').val() + "</style>" + $("#html").val());
document.getElementById('resultFrame').contentWindow.eval($('#js').val());
});
```

**LIVE** http://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/8y0yctn3/